# How to add youtube iFrame to fancybox?

Tags: youtube, fancybox

I am using FancyBox [http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/] for my image gallery. I was wondering if I can use it on YouTube iframe as well. Is there any way that I can add the YouTube iframe to FancyBox?

Answer (score 0):

The website shows that video are shown as links and will play when clicked.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"   href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cYplvwBvGA4?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque">Video #2</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VNPzA/